# MSSQL - How do I sum quantities based on ready date to feed into scatter plot chart?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2)

I'm trying to show how many parts are ready for a product as time progresses. I want to feed this into a scatter plot (I can do this part). I originally tried to approach this one the top of every hour, but a scatter plot I shouldn't need this. I will have better accuracy if I use the date stamp instead for the x axis instead of plotting 0-23HR and rounding the time.

The table looks like this:

```
+-------------+---------+---------+------+-------------------------+
| location_id | tray_id | part_id | qty  |        ready_at         |
+-------------+---------+---------+------+-------------------------+
|          21 |     024 |    1816 | 6461 | 2019-12-20 16:27:58.280 |
|          21 |     314 |    1816 | 6054 | 2019-12-20 16:27:58.280 |
|          21 |     359 |    1816 | 6668 | 2019-12-20 16:27:58.280 |
|          23 |     118 |    1816 | 6346 | 2019-12-21 08:07:25.733 |
|          23 |     239 |    1816 | 6656 | 2019-12-21 08:07:25.733 |
+-------------+---------+---------+------+-------------------------+
```

What I'm trying to return:

```
+---------+----------------+-------------------------+
| part_id | running total  |        ready_at         |
+---------+----------------+-------------------------+
|    1816 |          19183 | 2019-12-20 16:27:58.280 |
|    1816 |          32185 | 2019-12-21 08:07:25.733 |
+---------+----------------+-------------------------+
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

--EDIT
Richard Hansell answer worked for me. I was able to create a stored procedure to return the results I needed with a where clause to look at the specific part_id

You guys rock!

Comment: Try this `select part_id,sum(qty) over(order by part_id) as "running_total", ready_at from table`

Comment: @vhadalgi This just sums everything in qty. Doesn't show what is ready on 12-20-2019 vs 12-21-2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various answers here, but most of them don't cope with the fact that you have multiple identical dates in your data set.

Let's put your data into a table variable:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (location_id INT, tray_id CHAR(3), part_id INT, qty INT, ready_at DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @table 
SELECT 21, '024', 1816, 6461, '2019-12-20 16:27:58.280' UNION ALL
SELECT 21, '314', 1816, 6054, '2019-12-20 16:27:58.28' UNION ALL
SELECT 21, '359', 1816, 6668, '2019-12-20 16:27:58.280' UNION ALL
SELECT 23, '118', 1816, 6346, '2019-12-21 08:07:25.733' UNION ALL
SELECT 23, '239', 1816, 6656, '2019-12-21 08:07:25.733';
```

Now I can do this to get the results you asked for:

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT
        part_id,
        ready_at,
        SUM(qty) OVER (ORDER BY ready_at ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS running_total,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ready_at ORDER BY ready_at) AS order_id
    FROM
        @table)
SELECT
    part_id,
    ready_at,
    MAX(running_total) AS running_total
FROM 
    x
GROUP BY
    part_id,
    ready_at;
```

Results are:

```
part_id ready_at                running_total
1816    2019-12-20 16:27:58.280 19183
1816    2019-12-21 08:07:25.733 32185
```

Bonus method, you can also do this in reverse, which I feel is a little cleaner?

```
WITH y AS (
    SELECT
        part_id,
        ready_at,
        SUM(qty) AS running_total
    FROM
        @table
    GROUP BY
        part_id,
        ready_at)
SELECT
    part_id,
    ready_at,
    SUM(running_total) OVER (ORDER BY ready_at ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS running_total
FROM
    y;
```

Same results.

Comment: Doesn't work if you dataset contains multiple part_id's

Comment: I created a stored procedure with example one, I made a temp tbl with a where clause as a parameter to filter by part_id. Worked perfect. The other answer suggested gave strange results. parts would increase, and decrease(impossible) over time. not sure how/why this was happening.

Answer (score 0):

You need to partition by [ready_at]:

```
select distinct 
    part_id
    ,sum(qty) over (partition by ready_at ORDER BY part_id ) as running_total
    ,ready_at
from #tmp
```